# Localdb in Visual Studio 2015 error 52 (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio, database-connection, connection-string

I programmed an application with an attached `.mdf` database file that works fine on my computer. But on another computer (client PC) I get this error message :

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database
>   Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly
>   installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection

Should I install SQL Server Express on my client PC? It's just impossible, can you please help ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks mark for you answer , that mean I have to switch to Sqlite ? because I don't wanna install any thing on the client PC. can you please tell me what is the right choice to do? (I'm working under VS 2015) thanks in advance

Comment: Ok Mark, Thanks a lot. add you answer I'm gonna approve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a `.mdf` SQL Server database file, you **must** install at least SQL Server Express on that machine - or put the database on a SQL Server instance in the network the PC is connected to and use the database on the server.

You **cannot** use a `.mdf` database file totally without installed SQL Server - SQL Server is **not** an *embedded* database that works without installation. If you require such a database, look at SQLite, SQL Server CE (Compact Edition) or something like RavenDB. Those can be embedded (as a set of DLL's) into your solution and work against files on disk without need of installing a server component on the machine where they run.